# Node-RED parse json

Tags: json, node-red

I am trying to pull out the value "533"

```
{
  "d": {
    "ItemValue_1": 533
   },
   "ts": "2021-01-20T10:59:41.958591"
}
```

This does not work

```
var ItemValue_1 = msg.payload.ItemValue_1;
msg.payload = ItemValue_1;
return msg;
```

My result is unsuccessful

Comment: try `msg.payload.d.ItemValue_1`

Comment: Can I have the complete code? I'm new to node red

Comment: Please have a go first, @ArunpandianM's comment includes the correct object path to the value you want, compare it to what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve on my own, it works.

```
sensorMeasurement=JSON.parse(msg.payload);
msg.payload=sensorMeasurement.d;
var msgout = {payload : msg.payload.ItemValue_1}
return msgout;
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is as follows:

Add a JSON node before the function node, this will turn a string payload in to a JSON object (assuming the string actually represents a JSON object).

Then if you are using a function node the following:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.d.ItemValue_1;
return msg;
```

It is bad practice to create a new object as you did in your answer as it throws away any meta data that may be required later that is attached to the original object.

Rather than use a function node it would also be cleaner to use a change node and the Move mode to shift the `msg.payload.d.ItemValue_1` to `msg.payload`